# SIMD Vectors - Complex numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I am wanting to use the [System.Numerics.Vector](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Numerics) namespace in .NET Core, but I have run into the issue of there being no support for vectors of complex numbers. As it stands, the [Vector](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Numerics/Vector.cs) type will work with any primitive type, from byte to double. I am not a programmer by trade, so I can be ignorant of some low-level/conceptual stuff, but is there a reason why there isn't support for complex numbers? As far as I can see, perhaps the only issue would be that the Complex type is a managed struct. Could I not just extend the [Register](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Numerics/Register.cs) type to include `[FieldOffset(0)] internal Complex complex_0` and build new functions around that?

I am willing to work on the type extension myself, but wanted to ask if there is some reason why this wasn't included in the first place, since it seems like a lot of signal processing work would benefit greatly from complex vectors and SIMD.

Comment: A possible reason is that there is no direct hardware support for complex numbers. It's much more efficient to use two vectors, one for the real and one for the imaginary parts. (the relevant concept here is SoA vs. AoS)

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf on 6.6.1.1 shows possible CPU instructions for complex arithmetic. Of course, I am not sure how much this applies...

Comment: They *help* make it more efficient in cases where you're "stuck" with the AOS memory layout where real/imaginary pairs must be next to each other. But it is still far more efficient to separate real/imaginary pairs into different SIMD vectors.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate the advice. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: `System.Numerics.Vectors` contains SIMD accelerated types like `Vector<>`. I checked Complex and while part of this assembly it is not SIMD accelerated. As @Mysticial points to use SOA and can allow you to executed say 8 floating point mulitplications in parallel and with better cache utilization.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer Yes, I am using the SIMD Vectors.

Comment: Worth noting that drastically expanded SIMD support is being worked on for .NET Core. The GitHub issue is worth a read: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22940

Comment: @battlebottle thanks for sharing this! It definitely gave me a lot more hope for vectors. They hardly perform better than arrays at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Numerics.Vector is useless for your goal. You could rely on the Vector256 class from the System.Runtime.Intrinsics namespace. The necessary instructions are exposed in the System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Avx class.
(Vector128 would be of little help here, as it represents a single Complex number. I failed to locate any magic that would help me re-interpreting the Complex as Vector128 without copying, otherwise we would be able to boost up the built-in operators provided for the Complex class)

So, the idea is to

1. Have your Complex data expressed in terms of Span
2. Have the arithmetic operators implemented on those Spans
3. Internally, cast those Spans to Vector256
4. And use the Avx operations

See the sample code below:

```
public static class ComplexAvx
    {
        public static Span<Complex> Add(ReadOnlySpan<Complex> left, ReadOnlySpan<Complex> right)
        {
            var result = new Complex[Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length)].AsSpan();
            var vectorRes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(result);
            var vectorLeft = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(left);
            var vectorRight = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(right);
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorRes.Length; i++)
                vectorRes[i] = Avx.Add(vectorLeft[i], vectorRight[i]);

            for (int i = 2 * vectorRes.Length; i < result.Length; i++)
                result[i] = left[i] + right[i];
            return result;
        }

        public static Span<Complex> Subtract(ReadOnlySpan<Complex> left, ReadOnlySpan<Complex> right)
        {
            var result = new Complex[Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length)].AsSpan();
            var vectorRes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(result);
            var vectorLeft = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(left);
            var vectorRight = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(right);
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorRes.Length; i++)
                vectorRes[i] = Avx.Subtract(vectorLeft[i], vectorRight[i]);

            for (int i = 2 * vectorRes.Length; i < result.Length; i++)
                result[i] = left[i] - right[i];
            return result;
        }

        public static Span<Complex> Multiply(ReadOnlySpan<Complex> left, ReadOnlySpan<Complex> right)
        {
            var result = new Complex[Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length)].AsSpan();
            var vectorRes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(result);
            var vectorLeft = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(left);
            var vectorRight = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Complex, Vector256<double>>(right);
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorRes.Length; i++)
            {
                var l = vectorLeft[i];  
                var r = vectorRight[i]; 
                vectorRes[i] = Avx.HorizontalAdd(
                    Avx.Multiply(
                        Avx.Multiply(l, r), 
                        Vector256.Create(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0)), 
                    Avx.Multiply(
                        l, 
                        Avx.Permute(r, 0b0101)
                        )); 
            }
            for (int i = 2 * vectorRes.Length; i < result.Length; i++)
                result[i] = left[i] * right[i];
            return result;
        }

    }
```

This code performs 5 AVX operations for multiplying two complex numbers, whereas using the System.Numerics.Complex.Multiply would consume 8 multiplications and 4 additions.
(Of course, the code should check for Avx.IsEnabled - skipped that for brevity)
I haven't bothered with the benchmarks, so not sure how much (if at all) gain would it produce on the modern CPUs.
Avx512 would allow using same 5 instructions for handling 4 complex at once; but that's pending the CLR support yet.